# I'm going to work on the crontab every five minutes from 6 to 24

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm going to work on the crontab every five minutes from 6 to 24.
but It's a 5-minute cycle, but I'm trying to get it done 40 seconds earlier.
Then every time, 4 minutes and 20 seconds, 9 minutes and 20 seconds, 14 minutes and 20 seconds... Everything will be done.
So the crontab schedule I thought of is `20 4/5 6-24 * *`, did I set it up correctly?

Running every 5 minutes and sleeping for 4 minutes and 20 seconds seems inefficient.
And how do I do this in Window?

Comment: ```* * * * *```,five stars match minute hour day month weekday. You need more study.

Comment: 4-59/5 6-23 * * *  How about this?

Comment: And sleep 20seconds

Comment: 4/5 6-23 * * * and sleep 20 seconds in you script